# Convert string representation of numbers less than 1 to double

Tags: c#, string, double

Convert.ToDouble Method (String) converts the specified String representation of a number to an equivalent double-precision floating point number.

I have this line of code:
     double d = Convert.ToDouble("0.3");

and it gives me 3.0 instead of 0.3. For numbers greater than 1 it works as expected.
Why?

Comment: It works OK with CulturalInfo option: double d = Convert.ToDouble("0.3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: I think you mean `Convert.ToDouble("0,3")`  ;-)

Comment: It was like that but I wanted point, so I changed my cultural settings to the dot, and everything seemed to work fine, until I tried numbers less than zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely a locale problem. There are cultures where `.` is not the decimal separator.

Try `double.Parse("0.3",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo();
provider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
double d = Convert.ToDouble("0.3", provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the current Culture settings? It's probably because in the culture settings you are using the '.' is not the decimal delimiter!